# gsoap web service server - methods that accept string values?

Tags: c++, web-services, gsoap

I am working in ubuntu server 10.04

I am creating a test.h file which I want to contain 4 string values.

```
test.h
```

`int ns__take(string name, string user, string eyes, string result);` //the result will be a strcat  //of name user and eyes

**1**.It is ok? Can i have string values in gsoap web service server?

**2**. In test.cpp can I write inside `ns__take` method `result=strcat(name,user,eyes);`?

**3**.With these string values how can I programatically open a file and write the values in that file?
Each time a client accesses the web service I would like to save the input parameters in a file

**4.** Can multiple clients access the webservice in the same time? Will this affect in a bad way the file where i want to write the input parameters?

Need some help! THX . I am new to gsoap wsdl web service.

EDIT:

> HERE IS MY test.cpp

```
#include "soapH.h"
#include "tests.nsmap"
#include <math.h>
main()
{
soap_serve(soap_new());
}
int ns__take(struct soap *soap, std::string a, std::string b, std::string &result)
{
result=a+b;
//
..here i want to add the open file and write the values a,b.
do i need a synchronization if multiple clients acces in the same time the method?
how will that be?
//
return SOAP_OK;
}
```

I am compiling the tests.cgi using:

```
soapcpp2 test.h

> c++ -o tests.cgi test.cpp soapC.cpp soapServer.cpp -lgsoap++
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. yes
2. no, you do a `result=name+user+eyes` or some such, `string`, these are `std::string` class object
3. Just do it
4. That depends on how you implement the service. And yes, if you handle requests in parallel you'd have to take care of synchronization.
5. Why don't you try something before asking?

Comment: Hey. thx for replay. it works. everything ok till to point 4. I would like to ask you what do you mean by synchronuzation? I've post the currently test.cpp

Comment: appreciate very much your effort. I am new to gsoap, web service. I am working with wsdl and tests.cgi .

Comment: I think your test.cpp doesn't handle simultaneous requests in parallel, so you don't need to worry about synchronization.

Comment: how can i change the code for having simulanious requests in paralel?

Comment: There are many ways. Probably the easiest is to spawn a thread after accepting incoming connection. But you really have to put some effort of your own into it.

Comment: thx a lot michael. I will try to do it. I am in hurry. i don't have much time. i have to do a batch file too:(.